# Select only one column value based on id from table and use in function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

**Description**
I am creating a postgresql function and encountered a problem. I am reading data from table and based on that data i want to update data or not.

but for selection i need to either create a temp table or create another function that return a single decimal value.

**Here is my code**

```
Declare command text := 'select distance from road where gid ='|| id;
Execute command;
```

i am stuck at this point 
i dont know what to do as i am new to postgresql

**What i need**

i want to apply condition on distance returned by this query 
for example

```
IF distance < 100 
THEN
    (Insert into another table)
END;
```

**What i tried**

```
select distance into varDistance from road where gid ='|| id;
```

i go through Select Into command and came to know that this should be same as table . which is not acceptable to me .

**Is this possible to have double type variable and after query i get my varibale initialed with value? Or else solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what you are trying to do, but to read a single value from a table, you would need the [`select into`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Something along the lines:

```
create function some_function(p_id integer)
  returns ...
as
$$
declare
  l_distance double precision;
begin
  select distance 
     into l_distance
  from road
  where id = p_id; --<< this is the parameter

  if l_distance < 100 then 
    insert into some_other_table (...) 
    values (...)
  end if;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

From the little information you have provided, I don't see any reason for dynamic SQL.

If you do need dynamic SQL, use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to create the SQL string with a placeholder, then use `execute` [with an into and using clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

```
l_sql := format('select distance from %I gid = $1', l_table_name);
execute l_sql
  into l_distance
using p_id; --<< this is the parameter
```

Comment: This is owsum. but i need dynamic SQL because table name is also not known
let say command text := 'select distance from ' || tableName || ' where gid ='|| id;

Comment: you beauty.. Thanks a lot